# Trying to convert a Braintree nested callback into NodeJS async/await syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, braintree

I am trying to convert this Braintree nested callback into async/await:

```
  var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
    search.customerId().is(braintreeCustomerId);
  }, function (err, response) {
    response.each(function (err, transaction) {
      console.log(transaction);
    });
  });
```

I tried this approach but I am getting `undefined` response output:

```
  await gateway.transaction.search(async (search) => {
    const response = await search.customerId().is(braintreeCustomerId);
    console.log(response)
  })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `stream`? Do you need it?

Comment: No I don't need it - it was just used by the example in the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` functions shouldn't be generally used with APIs that are unaware of promise because this results in runaway promises that aren't chained.

If `gateway.transaction.search` doesn't support promises, it needs to be promisified:

```
const search = util.promisify(gateway.transaction.search).bind(gateway.transaction);

const searchResult = await search();
const response = searchResult.customerId().is(braintreeCustomerId);
```

If `searchResult.customerId().is(braintreeCustomerId)` doesn't return a promise, it doesn't need to be `await`ed.

Answer (score 0):

The promise will only help you with the final asynchronous result callback, not the predicate.

```
const response = await gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
  search.customerId().is(braintreeCustomerId);
});
response.each(function (err, transaction) {
  console.log(transaction);
});
```

This assumes that `transaction.search` already supports promises. If not, you will [need to promisify it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572).